# Sorting of photos based on filename endings

Tags: python

I am trying to sort photos from two folders and get photos ending in 1550_N from one folder and 1050_R_N from another folder. I wrote the below function for the same. The issue is with 1550 not all N are there in 1 to 150 but in 1050 folder all N are there from 1 to 150.

```py
    dir_name_1200 = "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/20201023_1ter_Reaktionstag/output_1200"
    dir_name_1550 = "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/20201023_1ter_Reaktionstag/output_1550"
    dir_name_1050 = "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/20201023_1ter_Reaktionstag/output_1050_old"


    def match_photos_for_calc(n, dir_name1, dir_name2):
    # x = str(n)
    for filename_1 in os.listdir(dir_name2):
        x = Path(filename_1).stem.split('_')[-1]
        # print(x)
        if x == str(n):
            print('yes')
            filename_dir1 = filename_1
    for filename in os.listdir(dir_name1):
        y = Path(filename).stem.split('_')[-1]
        # print(y)
        if y == str(n):
            z = '1050_R_' + y + '.'
            for filename_2 in os.listdir(dir_name_1050):
                if re.match(r'.*%s.*' % z, filename_2) is not None:
                    filename_dir2 = filename_2
                    return filename_dir1, filename_dir2



for i in range(1, 150):
    (filename_1550, filename_1050) = match_photos_for_calc(i, dir_name_1550, dir_name_1050)
    print(filename_1550)
    print(filename_1050)
```

But I am getting error for the above iteration as

```
 File "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Quellcode/sort.py", line 39, in <module>
    (filename_1550, filename_1050) = match_photos_for_calc(i, dir_name_1550, dir_name_1050)
  File "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Quellcode/sort.py", line 34, in match_photos_for_calc
    return filename_dir1, filename_dir2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename_dir1' referenced before assignment
```

If I directly put value of i =15 for which photos exist in both folders I get the correct result.

```
23_10_2020_15_48_07_1550_15.png
23_10_2020_15_48_10_1050_R_15.png
```

But when the photo doesn't exist in 1550 folder for a particular `i` I get the below error

```
    File "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Quellcode/sort.py", line 39, in <module>
    (filename_1550, filename_1050) = match_photos_for_calc(i, dir_name_1550, dir_name_1050)
    File "C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Quellcode/sort.py", line 34, in match_photos_for_calc
    return filename_dir1, filename_dir2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename_dir1' referenced before assignment
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you can use `is_file()` or `is_dir()` method if you have a pathlib `posix` object to check if the item exists before moving on with your code.

Comment: Hi, can you please give me an example where I can put it in the code

Comment: How do you want to handle a situation when a file doesn't exist in both folders? Pass on or raise an error?

Comment: I intend to pass on. how can I do that

Comment: My intention is the for loop should skip the number where photo doesnt exist in one of the folder and move on to next i

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method would be to just handle the error when it occurs by adding a `try..except` block around your function call statement (since you are using the results of your function call)

```py
   try:
       (filename_1550, filename_1050) = match_photos_for_calc(i, dir_name_1550, dir_name_1050)
   except UnboundLocalError:
       continue
```

Note: this is not the most elegant solution and is just a mere fix

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem with this?

Comment: I am using the output of this function. How can I make it work when the result is file doesnt exsist. I get the following error intensity_image_1550 = np.log10(np.divide(img_meth_1550, img_1550))  # calculate_intensity(img_meth_1550, img_1550)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Try this new approach, you will be able to skip all the code after your function call if the file doesn't exist

Comment: hey I am still getting the error  intensity_image_1550 = np.log10(np.divide(img_meth_1550, img_1550))  # calculate_intensity(img_meth_1550, img_1550)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: This error is different and not concerned with code what we have here in question. So, update the question so that people here can help you or I suggest you to step through your code using a debugger and I am sure you'll be able to pin point and solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

My further code is below

```
    for i in range(1, 150):
try:
    (filename_1550_i, filename_1050_i) = match_photos_for_calc(i, dir_name_1550, dir_name_1050)
except UnboundLocalError:
    continue

print(filename_1550_i)
print(filename_1050_i)
# for filename_1550 in os.listdir(dir_name_1550):
img_1550 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_name_1550, filename_1550_i))
img_meth_1550 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_ref, '23_10_2020_15_02_47_1550_5.png'))
img_1050 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_name_1050, filename_1050_i))
img_meth_1050 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_ref, '23_10_2020_15_02_29_1050_2.png'))


intensity_image_1550 = np.log10(np.divide(img_meth_1550, img_1550))  # calculate_intensity(img_meth_1550, img_1550)
plt.imshow(img_meth_1550)
plt.show()
intensity_image_1050 = np.log10(np.divide(img_meth_1050, img_1050))  # calculate_intensity(img_meth_1050, img_105050)
result = intensity_image_1050 - intensity_image_1550
print(result)
intensity_image = np.nan_to_num(result)
```

and I get the below error=
File "C:/Users/shiva/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/isabella.py", line 230, in 
intensity_image_1550 = np.log10(np.divide(img_meth_1550, img_1550))  # calculate_intensity(img_meth_1550, img_1550)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: seems like cv2 is not able to find the file at the path, if the filenames are valid then I would try to print the joined path and check if the path is correct